# Faster web scraping with R

Tags: html, r, web-scraping

I need help to speed up a web scraping with R.
I need to scrape some data from about 23.000 web pages but I need to do it faster than 2 hours (!) and I don't know how to improve my script to reach the goal (I'm new with R!).
Here's an example of the page: https://"sample"/46351 and every page is characterized by a code at the end of the url. In ***Codes$id*** there are all codes.
Can anyone give me any advice?
Are there any functions to speed up all?
Here attached the code.
Thanks a lot for the help!

```
> cr <- c()
> pr <- c()
> vig <- c()
> ges <- c()
> tabellafinale <- NULL
> tabellafinale <- data.table(ges,cr, pr, vig,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
> imp <- Codes$id
> str1 <- "https://"sample"/"
> for (p in 1:length(imp)) {
+   
+   try(   
+     {
+       str2 <- imp[p]
+       str3 <- paste(str1,str2,sep="")
+       page<-read_html(str3)    
+       carr<-html_text(html_nodes(page,".span3"))    
+       prez<-html_text(html_nodes(page,".carbFormat"))    
+       viag<-html_text(html_nodes(page,".span5"))    
+       gest <- str2    
+       carr<-gsub("\n","",carr)    
+       via<-gsub("\n","",via)
+       pre<-gsub("\n","",pre)
+       carr<-gsub("\r","",carr)
+       via<-gsub("\r","",via)
+       pre<-gsub("\r","",pre)
+       carr<-gsub("\t","",carr)
+       via<-gsub("\t","",via)
+       pre<-gsub("\t","",pre)
+       car <- data.table(carr)
+       n <- length(carr)
+       carb <- carr[7:n]
+       cr <- data.table(carb)
+       prezzi <- data.table(pre)
+       vigore <- data.table(via)
+       ges <- data.table(gest)
+       oss <- data.table(ges,cr, pr, vig, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
+       tabellafinale <- rbind(tabellafinale, oss)   
+     }
+     , silent=T
+   )
+   closeAllConnections()
+ }
```

Comment: Assuming this is one server, are you sure you're not DDOSing it? Still making the same assumption, there may be little you could do if you're being throttled on the server side.

Answer (score 2):

You can try :

```
library(rvest)

tabellafinale <- do.call(rbind, lapply(Codes$id, function(str2) {
  try({
    str3 <- paste0(str1,str2)
    page<-read_html(str3)
    carr<-html_text(html_nodes(page,".span3"))
    prez<-html_text(html_nodes(page,".carbFormat"))
    viag<-html_text(html_nodes(page,".span5"))
    carr<- gsub("[\n\r\t]","",carr)
    prez<- gsub("[\n\r\t]","",prez)
    viag<- gsub("[\n\r\t]","",viag)
    carb <- carr[7:length(carr)]
    data.frame(str2,carb, prez, viag, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  }, silent = TRUE)
}))
```

You can replace `do.call` `rbind` + `lapply` to `map_df` from `purrr`.

```
tabellafinale <- map_df(Codes$id, function(str2) {
   .....rest of the code
   .....as it is
})
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer but I have a doubt: where do I have to define str2? before I defined in try and as a function of p

Comment: @G_scrape7 `lapply` is kind of a loop which we apply on  `Codes$id`. So for first iteration `str2` is `Codes$id[1]`, for second it is `Codes$id[2]` and so on.